# Page title in grails displayed on the body

Tags: grails, layout

When I try to set the title of a view page using the title tag I got this title on the page body and I found the head tag to be empty. Here is the head of the page:

```
<head>      
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <title>Implementation Error</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'errors.css')}" type="text/css">
         <r:require modules="bootstrap"/>
</head>
```

When the page get rendered I got the following:

```
<body>
    Implementation Error

            <script src="/accountcontrol/static/plugins/jquery-1.7.2/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="/accountcontrol/static/bundle-fixtaglib_head.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection">
        <link href="/accountcontrol/static/bundle-bundle_bootstrap_head.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection">

            <link href="/accountcontrol/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/accountcontrol/static/js/lputil.js"></script>
</body>
```

what is going wrong with that?

Thanks,

Comment: No stacktrace, no exception, just "Implementation Error"?

Comment: Implementation Error is the title I set in the head of my view page. It is not an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this exact same issue with Grails 2.2 and it brought me here. After a lot of yak shaving, I found out that you need to look in your main.gsp layout file and actually wrap the layout title tag in a title tag like so:

```
 <title><g:layoutTitle/></title>
```

Once I did this, the problem went away. I must have looked at [this](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#layouts) page a million times and not seen that.

Answer (score 0):

Check your "main" layout and make sure that "g:layoutTitle" tag defined in head section. For more info see [layoutTitle docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/layoutTitle.html).